# I need help to convert this web.config rule to htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess, url-rewriting

I have this rule on my web.config document, and i need to convert in an htaccess rule.

```
<rule name="Redirect subdomain" enabled="true" patternSyntax="ECMAScript">
        <match url="^(.*)$" />
        <conditions>
            <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^([^/]+)\.([^/]+)\.com\.br$" />
        </conditions>
        <action type="Rewrite" url="/index.php?cliente={C:1}&amp;categoria=portal&amp;module=home&amp;do=index&amp;{QUERY_STRING}"
    />
    </rule>
```

I have tried this:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)subdomain.domain\.com\.br$ [NC]
RewriteRule^ /index.php?cliente={C:1}&amp;categoria=portal&amp;module=home&amp;do=index&amp;{QUERY_STRING}
```

But the parameter of "cliente" is aways empty.

Comment: let us know what you have tried

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Convert web.config file to .htaccess](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9591938/convert-web-config-file-to-htaccess). Sorry for my previous answer, I somehow misread the question.

Comment: Unfortunately that one does not help me. :(
I have a problem only with one of the parameters.
Is "cliente", that returns without a value.

Answer (score 0):

You need to match `{QUERY_STRING}` as well. See [htaccess RewriteRule page with query string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20383669/htaccess-rewriterule-page-with-query-string) for example.