# how translate web.config into .htaccess file

Tags: php, .htaccess, laravel, web-config

I have a Laravel web application hosted on an IIS8, this application has a web.config into the root of the project and another web.confing into the /public dir.
They are differents.
I no have an .htaccess file into the root but I have an .htaccess into my /public dir.
So I should transform this web.config into an .htaccess
How I can do it?
This is the web.config into root project

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
  <system.webServer>
        <rewrite>
            <rules>
                <rule name="Imported Rule 4">
                    <match url=".*" ignoreCase="false" />
                    <conditions>
                        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" ignoreCase="false" negate="true" />
                        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" ignoreCase="false" negate="true" />                     
                    </conditions>
                    <action type="Rewrite" url="/public/{R:0}" />
    </rule>
                <rule name="Imported Rule 3" stopProcessing="true">
                    <match url="^(.*)$" ignoreCase="false" />
                    <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
                        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" ignoreCase="false" negate="true" />
                        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" ignoreCase="false" negate="true" />                     
                    </conditions>
                    <action type="Rewrite" url="/public/index.php" />
                </rule>
            </rules>
        </rewrite>
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

the web.confing into /public dir is

```html
<configuration>
  <system.webServer>
    <rewrite>
      <rules>
        <rule name="Imported Rule 1" enabled="true" stopProcessing="true">
          <match url="^(.*)/$" ignoreCase="false" />
          <conditions>
            <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" ignoreCase="false" negate="true" />
          </conditions>
          <action type="Redirect" redirectType="Permanent" url="/{R:1}" />
        </rule>
        <rule name="Imported Rule 2" enabled="true" stopProcessing="true">
          <match url="^" ignoreCase="false" />
          <conditions>
            <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" ignoreCase="false" negate="true" />
            <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" ignoreCase="false" negate="true" />
          </conditions>
          <action type="Rewrite" url="index.php" />
        </rule>
      </rules>
    </rewrite>
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

I posted both beacuse I don't know which of these is the correct file.

I already have an .htaccess into my /public dir and it contains

```html
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews
    </IfModule>

    RewriteEngine On

    # Redirect Trailing Slashes...
    RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]

    # Handle Front Controller...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]

    RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
    RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
</IfModule>
```

So what is my problem? My problem is that this app on my local machine (I use xampp - apache and mysql) doesn't work very well.
Thanks to all for the answers!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Convert web.config file to .htaccess](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9591938/convert-web-config-file-to-htaccess)